# VertexAI pipelines ModelBatchPredictOp

Tags: python-3.x, list, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to perform a VertexAI BatchPrediction using 5 csv tables as instances to my custom model in model registry.

My problem is I get a consistent Value error of on my ModelBatchPredictOp pipeline method.

ValueError: Constant argument inputs must be one of type ['String', 'Integer', 'Float', 'Boolean', 'List', 'Dict'] Got: <google_cloud_pipeline_components.types.artifact_types.VertexModel object at xxxxxxxxxxx> of type <class 'google_cloud_pipeline_components.types.artifact_types.VertexModel'>.

I get a ValueError from the args below.

```
batch_predict_op = ModelBatchPredictOp(
    project=project_id,
    job_display_name="batch_prediction_job",
    model=model,
    gcs_source_uris=source_list,
    gcs_destination_output_uri_prefix=f"{bucket_name}",
    instances_format="csv",
    predictions_format="csv",
    #model_parameters={},
)
```

I think the error is coming from instances_format,gcs_source_uris of the args.

My input instances are a list of the following format.
`['gs://Folder/file1.csv','gs://Folder/file2.csv','gs://Folder/file3.csv' ......]`

I have tried replacing the gs with '/gcs/' with GCP Fuse recommends, but it doesn't help.

I have tried changing the instances_format to = List[str] , still same error.

This is google's documentation. It doesn't specify completely.
https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-2.0.0/api/v1/batch_predict_job.html#v1.batch_predict_job.ModelBatchPredictOp

Comment: Could you try again with one gcs `csv` file?

Comment: I tried to input one file instead of 5 and get the same error unfortunately

Comment: Is it possible to try again after enclosing all strings in double [quotation marks](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/get-batch-predictions#input_data_requirements) (") in a sample file.

Comment: Yes. Same error.

Comment: Can you try again after converting your sample csv file into json [file](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm)?Can you take a look at this [code](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex-p2p-predictions#5)(model\_id,) also.

Comment: I just tried a json and the same error. I don't think it's the input files but the model importing to the batchprediction.

Comment: What is the data type of the model?Can you make sure that `model` variable is correctly initialized?Can you try again after converting the model variable into string data type(using single quotes or using str()).Could you take a look at how ‘my\_mode\` declared in [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex-p2p-predictions#5) code?

Comment: I import the model as an artifact defining  the region, model_id which is given in the model registry, model_uid, and metadata. It is loaded into the model registry but do not have an endpoint. Must it have an endpoint  ?

Comment: Hi @Paul,Could you follow these [link1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9fU1xwBQYU) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/batchprediction-component) regarding the endpoint? It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.